# SQL to calculate time difference between two different rows and column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with two fields datetime, one is Start other End.

Example

```
select Start , End   from   launchings   where id = 210423 order by 1 asc
```

My result is

```
2013-11-01 08:30:00.000 2013-11-01 12:00:00.000
2013-11-01 13:00:00.000 2013-11-01 19:00:00.000
2013-11-01 19:00:00.000 2013-11-01 20:00:00.000
2013-11-01 19:00:00.000 2013-11-01 20:00:00.000

2013-11-04 08:30:00.000 2013-11-04 12:00:00.000
2013-11-04 13:00:00.000 2013-11-04 19:30:00.000
```

I need get the first and the last time a day and the interval between them, which would for example lunchtime

Example
     Day 04 - Result that I want

```
    Day         Start   Start interval   End interval   End
2013-11-04 -    08:00      12:00             13:00      19:30    
2013-11-01 -    08:30      12:00             13:00      20:00
```

Start and End I did. I need Interval

```
  SELECT 
    convert(char(10), DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Inicio), 0),103) AS Day,    
    MIN(convert(char(5),Inicio,108)) AS MinDate,    
    MAX(convert(char(5),Fim,108)) AS MaxDate

from   Lancamentos where matricula = 210423 
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Inicio), 0)
```

Result

```
Day         MinDate MaxDate
01/11/2013  08:30   20:00
04/11/2013  08:30   19:30
```

Comment: modified the question

Comment: Better now :) What if there are multiple breaks/intervals per day?

Comment: I need only the first, because it's lunch time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this is to use ROW_NUMBER() to put your results in order by day:

```
WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  [Date] = CAST(Start AS DATE),
            [Start],
            [End],
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, CAST(Start AS DATE) ORDER BY Start)
    FROM    Launchings
    WHERE   ID = 210423
)
SELECT  Date,
        [Start1] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Start END),
        [End1] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN [End] END)
        [Start2] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN Start END),
        [End2] = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN [End] END)
FROM    RankedData
GROUP BY Date;
```

---

**EDIT**

Sorry, missed the SQL-Server 2005 part of the question:

```
WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  [Date] = CAST(Start AS DATE),
            [Start],
            [End],
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start), 0) ORDER BY Start)
    FROM    Launchings
    WHERE   ID = 210423
)
SELECT  Date,
        [Start1] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Start END),
        [End1] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN [End] END)
        [Start2] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN Start END),
        [End2] = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN [End] END)
FROM    RankedData
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth

type date CAST(Start AS DATE) in sql 2005?

Answer (score 0):

```
--GarethD you still missed the SQL 2005 part of the question on the second line.
--But I think it's easy you should meant something like this: 

--Didn't test it.`
WITH RankedData AS
(   SELECT  [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start), 0),
            [Start],
            [End],
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start), 0) ORDER BY Start)
    FROM    Launchings
    WHERE   ID = 210423
)
SELECT  Date,
        [Start1] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Start END),
        [End1] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN [End] END)
        [Start2] = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN Start END),
        [End2] = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum > 1 THEN [End] END)
FROM    RankedData
GROUP BY Date;`
```